# Hide button inside a table after form submit?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

So, I'm trying to make a row containing a delete button to .hide after pressing delete.
The problem is.. The delete button submits a form, I can't pre-define my button class/ID because it's beeing echo'd multiple times (php script reads a dir, then puts all files in a table)

this is the current script, It does post the form in the background, But it doesn't hide the element, I tried some stuff myself but the script then ended up hiding all the buttons on the page or it won't work at all..

The button beeing echo'd:

```
echo "<input type='submit' value='delete' name='submit'>";
```

The Script behind it:

```
$("#delform").submit(function() {

    var url = "../../setdel.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("#delform").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
             // location.reload(); // show response from the php script.
           }
         });

    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```

Comment: @PHPglue OP is using a `submit` button which will generally cause a page postback/refresh anyway

Comment: I don't know any other way, My script reads out a dir from the user currently logged in, Then displays all files in a table, And the only way I know how to handle a delete is using a form which is submitting to a php file that is deleting the selected file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Catch the button's onclick instead of catching the submission. Example:

```
echo "<input type='submit' value='delete' name='delete' class='trigger_delete'>";
                                            //  ^^ don't name your buttons as submit
                                            // it will conflict to .submit() method
```

The on JS:

```
$('.trigger_delete').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent triggering submit
    var url = "../../setdel.php";

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: $("#delform").serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            $(e.target).closest('tr').hide(); // or .fadeOut();
        }(e) // <--- this one
     });
});
```

Comment: It does delete, But this is only hiding all the delete buttons within this table, The rows are still there :)

Comment: @Sjef92 okay so i does delete, check my revision, i forgot to reference the object that triggered the button, try it again

Comment: Still only the delete button, this time not all delete buttons but only the one specified. So it's progress! :D

Comment: @Sjef92 ahh so what you really want is the whole row that will be deleted, not the button itself?, so this button is inside a `<tr><td><input delete></td></tr>` something like this?

Comment: @Sjef92 check my revision again, should delete the whole row instead of just the button instead